# ngFor & ngIf to show&hide object detail

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular-ng-if

I have component like this

```
@Component({
  templateUrl:"home.html",
})
export class HomePage {
  current:any
  heroes=[{name:"hero1",detail:"h1detail"}, {name:"hero2",detail:"h2detail"}]

  constructor() {

    }

    tdetail(h){
      if (current!=h.name){
          current = h.name
      }
      else{
        current = ""
      }
    }
}
```

and html template home.html

```
<ion-navbar positive *navbar>
    <ion-title>
        Hero
    </ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
<ion-content class="xm-new-order">
  <ul class="event">
    <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
      <button (click)="tdetail(hero)">
        {{hero.name}}
      </button>
      <p *ngIf="current==hero.name" >
        {{hero.detail}}
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</ion-content>
```

Code will display a list of hero name buttons. When I click any button, I want to toggle show/hide hero details, but it is not happening. How can I fix this?

*edit: typo*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is in your `tdetail(h)` function. Here : `if (current!=hero.name){`, there is no `hero` variable defined. Here, it is passed as `h`. So, you need to use `h` like this:

```
tdetail(h){
  if (this.current!=h.name){
      this.current = h.name
  }
}
```

**EDIT 1:** Remove that else part. If you want to toggle, `current` should hold at least 1 value from `heros` at given point. In, your else part you are setting `current = "";` which resets current to empty string.

**EDIT 2:** Also, use `this.current` than `current`.

Comment: sorry, that my typo but even change hero to "h". it's still not work. https://plnkr.co/edit/Rg6kDt9C8WElTZH0FVxl?p=preview

Comment: Edited my answer. Have a look. In plunker it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below HTML for your hero list:

```
<ul class="event">
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
    <button (click)="hero.active = !hero.active">
      {{hero.name}}
    </button>
    <p *ngIf="hero.active">
      {{hero.detail}}
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```